# Iglob finding latest created, not latest modified

Tags: python, glob

From all i can see this line should find the latest file modified in the downloads folder that has the substring "orders"

orderFile = max(glob.iglob("C:\Users\hermo\Downloads\Orders*"), key=os.path.getctime)

but when having two file with the substring orders, then modifying the oldest of them, the code stil returns the other non modified file. so I belive it look for the latest created, not the latest modified. I can find any leads on google. since everyone defines this code as "finding the latest modified", but it does not do that. at least not for me. is there an alternative to getchtime that actually finds the last modified

to be sure I show the right problem i want to reference this picture. here the the code would return the "orders_2021..." since that is an exported file that was created at 15:38. order_custom was created many days ago and is just going to be the same file that user modifies when needed. now we need to "save as" and give it a new name every time(between exports) to make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got is. I needed to use getmtime not getctime. sorry about that. going to keep this in case someone else is has this problem.